# Keep certain slides in sync across PowerPoint decks

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I have two PowerPoint presentations that I’m continuously updating, with the following slide sequences:

1. `A B C D E F`
2. `A B C G H I`

As you can see, the first three slides in both decks start out identical, but they have to be kept in sync manually, as updates are made. Is there a way to automatically keep them in sync, such as by making slide `A` in presentation 2 a “symlink” to slide `A` in presentation 1?

I’m using the latest versions of PowerPoint for Mac and macOS, along with M365 Business Premium.

Comment: It might be simpler to put all of the slides into one file, then create custom shows that include just the slides/slide order for each version. Then on the first slide, add links to start each custom show.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - using custom shows mostly works. A major missing feature, when taking the custom show approach in PowerPoint for Mac, appears to be the ability to export custom shows as PDFs. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Another limitation of the custom show approach: slides are not dynamically numbered according to the custom show sequence (whether when presenting, or in exported PDFs).

Comment: Re PDFs: In PowerPoint for Windows, once you've chosen to save as PDF, you can click an Options button; one of the available options is to print all pages, a range of pages or to pick a defined custom show. I don't know if Mac PowerPoint offers this. If not, do you have access to a Windows PC? Or perhaps the web version has this option?

Comment: Yes, I can start my Windows VM and export to PDF in PowerPoint there (tested it, and it works), but that's not ideal. Good idea on the web version, but it looks like it's unfortunately not supported there either.

Comment: "Not ideal"  Understood.  But until MS/Apple cooperate in letting Microsoft use the same underlying code for PDF export on the Mac as they do in Windows, we're sort of stuck with the semi-crippled PDF export that Mac PPT offers us.